# state design pattern - how to implement it with Open-Close Principle

Tags: java, design-patterns, solid-principles

I implemented the state design pattern in Java with two states: Locked and Unlocked.
The initial state is Lock. if the user enters the code (password), It changes to Unlock, Then if the user enters '0', it changes to Lock state.

The problem with my current code implementation is that if I want to add another state - example: SemiLocked, I will also have to change the evKey function in the Locked, Unlocked classes, so that they allow a transition to the new state of SemiLocked. (example: user entering the right code will not change anymore to Unlock, but to SemiLocked)

How to implement it better with fewer required changes if I add more states in the future?

Current code:

```
public class SecretKeeper {
    private int secretCode;
    String secret1, secret2;
    private State state = new Locked(); 

    public SecretKeeper(int secretCode, String secret1, String secret2){
        this.secretCode=secretCode;
        this.secret1=secret1;
        this.secret2=secret2;
    }

    void printSecret1(){
        System.out.println(secret1);
    }

    void printSecret2(){
        System.out.println(secret2);
    }

    public boolean checkCode(int code){
        return code==secretCode;
    }

    void evKey(int digit){
        state.evKey(this, digit);
    }
    
    public void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}

public interface State {
    void evKey(SecretKeeper sk, int digit);
}
 
public class Locked implements State{
    int code = 0;
    @Override
    public void evKey(SecretKeeper sk, int digit) {
        if (digit == 0) code = 0;
        else code = code*10+digit;
        if (sk.checkCode(code)) sk.setState(new Unlocked());
    }
}

public class Unlocked implements State{
    @Override
    public void evKey(SecretKeeper sk, int digit) {
        if (digit == 0) sk.setState(new Locked());
        else if (digit == 1) sk.printSecret1();
        else if (digit == 2) sk.printSecret2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that follows OCP.

```
public class SecretKeeper {
    private int secretCode;
    private String secret1, secret2;
    private State state;

    //...

  void evKey(int digit) {
        state.setCode(digit);
        state.doStuff();
        boolean isSuccess = checkCode(state.getCode());
        if(isSuccess){
            state = state.getSwitchedState();
        }
    }

    //...
}
```

```
public interface State {
    void setCode(int digit);
    int getCode();
    State getSwitchedState();
    void doStuff();
}
```

```
public class LockedState implements State {
    private int code = 0;

    @Override
    public void setCode(int digit) {
        if (digit == 0) code = 0;
        else code = code * 10 + digit;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public State getSwitchedState() {
        return new SemiLockedState();
    }

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        // implement behavior for LockedState
    }
}

public class UnlockedState implements State {
    private int code = 0;

    @Override
    public void setCode(int digit) {
        code = digit;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @Override
    public State getSwitchedState() {
        return new LockedState(); // Modify as per requirement
    }

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
       if (getCode() == 1) SecretKeeper.printSecret1();
       else if (getCode() == 2) SecretKeeper.printSecret2();
       
    }
}
```